# My code prints out the address instead of the array value?

Tags: c++

What is wrong with my code? I want to print out the array, but when I try to do so it seems to print out an address instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int array[9]= {0};

    for (int i=0;i<=8;i++)
    {
        array[i]= (rand()%101);
    }

    cout<< array;

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "how to copy/paste code easier on this website? it so long and boring adding manually 4 spaces?" Use the code button that looks like `[{}]`.

Comment: Your intitializaiton is wrong and the way you print it is also not correct. Check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) for a basic tutorial on arrays.

Comment: @AurA Why do you think initialization is wrong ? `{0}` fills all the elements in the sequence to `0`.

Comment: @Mahesh Initialization is unnecessary here since he is already populating the array with random values. You are correct, it is not wrong but unnecessary.

Comment: @AurA He's not wrong, but you said he's wrong. It's unnecessary in this case, but good practice in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just `cout` an array. Arrays are not `cout`-able. Whenever you successfully `cout` something of type `T`, it means that there's a dedicated overloaded `<<` operator designed specifically to `cout` values of type `T`. And there's no dedicated `<<` operator for `cout`-ing arrays (aside from strings). For this reason the compiler chooses the closest match for the given argument type: a `<<` operator for pointers. Since arrays are convertible to pointers, that `<<` is applicable here.

If you want to `cout` the values of all elements of your array, you'll have to either `cout` them manually, one by one, or use some standard algorithm that can do it for you. For example

```
std::copy(array, array + 9, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do a loop to output each array element on its own.

The problem is that C++ doesn't always know the size of the array, so it can't default to outputting the whole thing as you would expect.

Comment: Highlight the code and use the `{}` tag; edit from there if necessary (at least, that's how I do it)

Comment: @Napster, I do it the same as tmpearce, except I'd call the `{}` a button. Once you've done it a couple of times it will be second nature.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the array and print each element like how you assigned value at each index. Since array *decays* to a pointer to the first element in the sequence, you are getting the address.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cout` doesn't have an overload for `int array[9]`, so this decays to a pointer (`int*`) and this is what you'll see displayed (something like `0x7fffe47142d0`).

To print the `int`s in the array individually, you will need to use a loop construct (like the `for`- loop you are using for populating the array) and send each of the `int`s to `std::cout` in turn, perhaps with some whitespace to format them.

Once you get the hang of C++ and its standard library, you may want to investigate how to do this with [**`std::copy()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), but I suspect this is a bit advanced for your homework.

Answer (score 0):

C++ decays array type to a pointer type when the value is passed as argument to a function.  C++11 has `std::array` (and TR1 specifies `std::tr1::array`) which retains the size of the array.  Here is your example modified to use `std::array`:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ostm, const std::array<T, N>& a)
{
  for (auto const& x : a)
    ostm << x << ' ';

  return ostm;
}

int main ()

{
    srand(time(NULL));

    std::array<int, 9> array;
    for (auto& x : array)
        x = rand() % 101;

    std::cout<< array << std::endl;
}
```